# Verbena leaves getting yellow dots and losing pigment

Tags: diagnosis, plant-health, diseases, leaves, discoloration

My verbena is getting yellow dots. It starts with a few of them and then the number of them grows until the leaf turns entirely a lighter shade of green. Comparing it to my other verbena, I think the stalk has gotten lighter as well (entirely, not in the speckled manner like the leaves)

Here's an image of the entire plant:
[image: 1]
And a close-up of the leaves:
[image: closeup]
And a few notes:

- it's more prominent in older leaves, but I've seen a few dots on the youngest ones as well
- I've inspected the plant and found no pests (no web from spider mites either - if you see white lines in the images, it's cat hair)
- there is no difference between the vein and the rest of the leaf, all parts get affected equaly
- not sure how well the images show it, but the edges of this pigment variation is not super rigid, it's more gradual
- there is no difference when touching the normal leaf parts and the yellowish doted parts - there's no bumps or indents
- the underside of the leaves looks normal
- the more the leaves are affected the dryer they are when touching them
- other plants in the vicinity are not affected

Living conditions of the plant:

- I water it regularly (only when the top of the soil is dry to touch)
- it is located where there's direct sunlight throughout most of the day

I live on the Adriatic coast. The temperature in the daytime is around 30-32°C (sometimes reaching even 35), while in the night it's about 20-22°C (day-night temperature fluctuation was enough for my petunias to get more whiteish blooms)

A few more potentially relevant notes:

- there has been a month or so of drought until it finally rained at the end of may (only for about a day or two, after which it got quite windy) - I'm pretty sure the spots already appeared before it rained, but it's gotten more severe since
- during the bad weather period and ever since, it has been very humid (my other verbena developed a very mild case of powdery mildew in this time)
  -humidity is currently around 50% and has been gradually decreasing each day
- since around this period the verbenas have had blossom drop (which I thought was maybe stress from weather changes) - while not as blooming as before, they are still developing new blossoms (one of which just bloomed this morning)